# Variables not flowing?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get my edit page working for my simple news system. What I want it to do is display all of the news items on click, which it does, but then I want to be able to click on title and be redirected to the switch and display a form with all of the information for that certain title, and then be able to edit it. Unfortunately, whenever I click on the title, nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style.css" />
</head>

<body>  
    <div align="center" /><font size="20px;" />#test</font></div>
    <?php include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>

    <fieldset><legend>Article editting</legend>
    <?php
    $idGlobal;
    include("includes/config.php");
    global $idGlobal;
        if(isset($_GET['x'])) {
            $x = $_GET['x'];
            switch($x) {

                case "$idGlobal":
                    if(is_null($idGlobal)) {
                        // if $the_id variable is null (empty) it will display the message below.
                        echo("Error. No id pushed.");
                    } elseif(isset($idGlobal)) {
                        // if $the_id variable is set (is storing a variable) it will display the form below.
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$idGlobal") or die(mysql_error());
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo('<form action="includes/process.php?x=edit" method="post" />');
                            echo('<input name="title" type="text" value="$row[\'title\']"/><br />');
                            echo('<input name="date" type="text" value="$row[\'date\']"/><br />');
                            echo('<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="text" />$row[\'text\'];</textarea><br />');
                            echo('<input name="author" type="text" value="$row[\'Author\']"/><br />');
                            echo('<input type="submit" />');
                            echo('</form>');
                        }
                    }
                break;

                default:
                    echo("<table>");
                    echo("<tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Author</th></tr>");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                          $id = $row['id'];

                            echo "<tr><td>"; 
                            echo $row['id'];
                            echo "</td><td>"; 
                            echo("<a href=\"edit.php?x=$id\" />" .$row['title'] . "</a>");
                            echo("</td><td>");
                            echo $row['date'];
                            echo("</td><td>");
                            echo $row['author'];
                            echo("</td></tr>");
                            $idGlobal = $id;
                        }
                break;
            }
        } else {
            echo("<table>");
            echo("<tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Author</th></tr>");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                  $id = $row['id'];

                    echo "<tr><td>"; 
                    echo $row['id'];
                    echo "</td><td>"; 
                    echo("<a href=\"edit.php?x=$id\" />" .$row['title'] . "</a>");
                    echo("</td><td>");
                    echo $row['date'];
                    echo("</td><td>");
                    echo $row['author'];
                    echo("</td></tr>");
                    $idGlobal = $id;
                }
        }
    ?>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line as an example for the rest:

```
echo('<input name="title" type="text" value="$row[\'title\']"/><br />');
```

Variable interpolation in PHP only occurs in double quoted strings, and the interpolation of subscripted variables requires surrounding the variable in braces:

```
echo("<input name=\"title\" type=\"text\" value=\"{$row['title']}\"/><br />");
```

Beware of other issues in your code though, including the lack of escaping of text in the HTML context, which can easily lead to an injection attack, given input with `"` for example.

Comment: Would this also be a problem with the textarea I have?

Comment: Yes, instead of `$row[\'text\'];` you need `{$row['text']}` and the whole string in double quotes, along with escaping the other double quotes already in the string. However, instead of interpolating the database value directly, you should really use `htmlspecialchars()` on all of the values you are about to interpolate first, then interpolate the escaped strings instead.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll look into making the fixes. :) Now just to wait until someone might be able to help me with my issue.